# How to search for source packages?

Tags: search, aptitude, source-packages

I can use **aptitude** to search for packages using a search term. For example, to search for all packages whose name begins with **Foo**:

```
$ aptitude search Foo*
```

However, this listing does not include **source packages** (package with source code).

How do I search and list source packages using a search term?

Comment: are you referring to http://packages.ubuntu.com/ ?

Answer (score 0):

Searching: I don't know how to perform a regex search over source package names using apt on the target machine, but one can perform a regex search over source package names by selecting "Source package names" under "Search package directories" at http://packages.ubuntu.com

Listing: Once you know the source package name 'foo', `apt-cache showsrc foo` shows the source package records for foo.

Answer (score 0):

this is what I do (besides what is listed) using unity as a example

```
apt-cache policy unity*
```

or 
This is a much larger list that shows you  the control files of packages
   apt-cache show unity*

Or you can use 'dump' to dump everything (not recommended)

```
apt-cache dump unity*
```

Or you can use dpkg also like

```
dpkg-query -l | grep unity*
```

Or you could use

```
apt-cache showpkg unity*
```

Hope this helps

Comment: For the penultimate line, `dpkg -l | grep unity` will do the job perfectly. :). No need to use `dpkg-query`. Besides, you must make sure to use correct regular expressions with `grep`: your `unity*` will also match on `unit` __not__ followed by `y`, because you've just specified "unit" plus "letter y 0 to n times". Perhaps you actually intended to use `unity.*` instead.